# Tkinter inserts separating space between two widgets(canvases)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a GUI with tkinter and all goes well apart from one thing which annoys me. I have drawn two canvases and I grid'ed them on my tk.Tk() root window on row=0,col=0 and row=1,col=0. I have set their backgrounds to 'red' and 'yellow'.

Once I run this program I expect the canvases to be exactly on top of each other(where red area finishes the yellow should start). However there is a thin annoying white space separating the canvases. My root main window is '800x640'. The height of the two canvases are 590 and 50. The math seems to be right. I have tried with .pack() as well instead of grid. Same result. This is the code:

```
watch = tk.Tk()
watch.geometry('800x640')
#app = Application_GUI(watch).pack()
canvas = tk.Canvas(watch, width=800, height=50, bg='red', bd=0)
canvas2 = tk.Canvas(watch, width=800, height=590, bg='yellow')
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=0)
canvas2.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=0)
watch.mainloop()
```

I have googled around but I can't find a solution to this problem. I notice that if I increase the height of the first canvas the white space gets covered but I don't want to do that I want to understand why my canvases leave that extra space when their heights summed togheter give the height of the root window. 
Please help me understand this issue and help me find a solution to get rid of that annoying white space. Thank you.

Edit: As jasonharper mentioned highlightthickness=0 solves this issue.

Comment: Can you add some image for the result you got initialy and later ?

Comment: You need to set the `highlightthickess` of both canvasses to 0.

Comment: Yep, the highlightthickness did the trick. Gotta read about that. Thank you! :D

Comment: if you want post a reply and i will accept it as solution